# Why do my white shoelaces get blue when exposed to UV?

Tags: visible-light

My shoes and shoelaces are both white. But when there is a UV light only my shoelaces appeared in a different colour. What is the reason?

[image]

Comment: Do you know what your shoelaces are made of?

Comment: @Jonas no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shoes and shoelaces are made from different materials. The shoelaces contain a substance that *fluoresces*: it converts the UV light to blue light so that it becomes visible to you. The remainder of the shoes does not contain this substance, so it just absorbs or reflects the UV light, still invisible to you.

There are many blue fluorescent substances, so we don't know which one it is from looking at the picture.  The intensity of the glow makes clear, that the shoelaces were especially designed to glow in UV.

Btw, fluorescent substances are also contained in some detergents (but in smaller amounts), where they appear as "optical brighteners" on the ingredients list. They too convert UV into visible light and make, for example, white shirts look bright & shiny in sunlight (which contains UV) and night clubs.